# How to replace string if they are in file

Tags: awk

I tried this command:

```
awk 'sub(/S/,"5")' primare.txt > primaro.txt
```

but the `primaro.txt` is empty.

`S` in primare.txt might be missing.
When there is no `S` I would like to print the same file as `primare.txt`.

**EDIT**

And how to repalce spaces by nothing?

```
awk 'sub(/ /,"") 1' parametrx10.txt

awk '{sub(/ /,"");print}' parametrx10.txt
```

These deleted only one space: `-8.3 7 6 0 4 O` > `-8.37 6 0 4 O`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following

```
awk '{sub(/[sS]/,"5")} 1' Input_file > out_file
```

Use `gsub` in place of sub in case you want to replace all occurrences of s. Also this will replace small and capital both s. So in case of capital letter replacement stick with your pattern.

Also on your comment section removing spaces.

```
awk '{gsub(/ +/,"")} 1' Input_file > out_file
```

Answer (score 2):

How about like this:

```
awk 'sub(/S/,"5") 1' primare.txt
```

Try it, if it's okay then add the `> primaro.txt` part yourself.
Also, maybe what you need is `gsub` instead of `sub`.

However, this thing I would suggest you to use `sed`:

```
sed 's|S|5|' primare.txt
```

Use `-i` switch to change file in place (better backup first).
Change to `s|S|5|g` to replace all occurances.

Replace spaces:

```
awk 'gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"") 1' primare.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you help me with edit in my question?

Comment: @Arrara  Check last one.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
awk '{sub(/S/,"5");print}'
```

Comment: And how to replace all spaces with nothing? `awk '{sub(/ /,"");print}' parametrx10.txt > parametry.txt`  this deleted only one space: `-8.3 7 6 0 4 O > -8.37 6 0 4 O`